# Creating method filters

Tags: java, language-agnostic, filter

In my code I have a `List<Person>`. Attributes to the objects in this list may include something along the lines of:

- ID
- First Name
- Last Name

In a part of my application, I will be allowing the user to search for a specific person by using any combination of those three values. At the moment, I have a switch statement simply checking which fields are filled out, and calling the method designated for that combination of values.

i.e.:

```
switch typeOfSearch    
if 0, lookById()    
if 1, lookByIdAndName()  
if 2, lookByFirstName()
```

and so on. There are actually 7 different types.

This makes me have one method for each statement. Is this a 'good' way to do this? Is there a way that I should use a parameter or some sort of 'filter'? It may not make a difference, but I'm coding this in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something more elgant with maps and interfaces. Try this for example,

```
interface LookUp{
    lookUpBy(HttpRequest req);
}

Map<Integer, LookUp> map = new HashMap<Integer, LookUp>();

map.put(0, new LookUpById());
map.put(1, new LookUpByIdAndName());
```

...

in your **controller** then you can do

```
int type = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(type));
Person person = map.get(type).lookUpBy(request);
```

This way you can quickly look up the method with a map. Of course you can also use a long switch but I feel this is more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

If good means "the language does it for me", no.

If good means 'readable', I would define in Person a method match() that returns true if the object matches your search criteria. Also, probably is a good way to create a method Criteria where you can encapsulate the criteria of search (which fields are you looking for and which value) and pass it to match(Criteria criteria).

Answer (score 0):

This way of doing quickly becomes unmanageable, since the number of combinations quickly becomes huge.
Create a PersonFilter class having all the possible query parameters, and visit each person of the list :

```
private class PersonFilter {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // constructor omitted

    public boolean accept(Person p) {
        if (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(p.getId()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.firstName != null && !this.firstName.equals(p.getFirstName()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.lastName != null && !this.lastName.equals(p.getLastName()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The filtering is now implemented by

```
public List<Person> filter(List<Person> list, PersonFilter filter) {
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person p : list) {
        if (filter.accept(p) {
            result.add(p);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point you should take a look at something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) which will give you the best scalability, manageability and performance for this type of searching.  Not knowing the amount of data your dealing with I **only** recommend this for a longer term solution with a larger set of objects to search with.  It's an amazing tool!